# Using -fsanitizer on vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using -fsanitizer while compiling programs helps in finding location of memory leaks easily. But how to use this with vscode.
I only know that for compiling a program in vscode through terminal we need to type in **g++ file_name.cpp -o executable_name.exe** and for running **.\program_name** 
Adding -fsanitizer to this command as an argument does not work for me. How to compile your program using fsanitizer on vscode?

Edit: I have been trying to use it as
**g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -fsanitize=address
tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempcodeRunnerfile.exe**
But this keeps giving me some kind of error:
**C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: Add it to the *compiler* flags? There's a few misconceptions here that need to be addressed before we can address sanitizers - the first of which is that `.\program_name` *runs* a program which was already compiled by some means (e.g. by VSCode invoking gcc/clang/MSVC for you, or by you doing the same thing manually)

Comment: @nanofarad oh sorry i mistyped things. Btw what do you mean by compiler flags?

Comment: The compiler flags are the flags (options) which are passed to the compiler (whose job it is to convert your human-readable C/C++ code into the executable binary)

Answer (score 1):

This is unrelated to VSCode. The problem is your platform - MinGW traditionally has poor sanitizer support.

Your [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), `MINGW64`, only supports UBSAN (with stripped-down error reporting, compile with `-fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error`).

There's also `CLANG64` environment, which does have ASAN. Install its Clang (`pacman -S mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-clang`), and compile using `clang++` located at `C:\msys64\clang64\bin`. If you're compiling from MSYS2 terminal, make sure you start the right one: launch it with `clang64.exe`, or the "MSYS2 Clang x64" shortcut (I don't remember the exact name).

Comment: g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error  tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempcodeRunnerfile.exe   
Using this command does not show the required details that should be displayed by -fsanitize on memory leak though

Comment: @Adyy There's no "the sanitizer". This enables UBSAN (Undefined Behavior SANitizer, which detects UB, not leaks), not ASAN (Address SANitizer, which among other things reports leaks).

Comment: i think i have now screwed up my vscode badly in order to setup clang. ;((( . Now iostream is not being recognized

Comment: @Adyy We can't help without more details.

Comment: should i make another post with all the my configuration files and the setup i have done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570270/setting-up-vscode-with-msys2-clang