# Setting up vscode with msys2 clang

Tags: visual-studio-code, msys2

I was trying to switch my Vscode from msys2 gcc to msys2 clang. I have downloaded clang according to the msys2 documentation provided. I have also followed the visual studio documentation for setting up clang. But my visual code fails to recognize iostream header.

I updated my environment path:

[image]

[image]

I also updated required include paths in my vs code configuration files:

[image]

[image]

cpp_properties:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/msys64/clang64/include",
                "C:/msys64/clang64/include/**",
                "C:/msys64/clang64",
                "C:/msys64/clang64/include/c++/v1",
                "C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/14.0.4/include",
                "C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/14.0.4/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/msys64/clang64/bin",
                "C:/msys64"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.19041.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/clang64/bin/clang++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/msys64/clang64/include",
                    "C:/msys64/clang64/include/**",
                    "C:/msys64/clang64/include/c++/v1",
                    "C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/14.0.4/include",
                    "C:/msys64/clang64/lib/clang/14.0.4/include/**",
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/msys64/clang64/bin",
                    "C:/msys64"
                ],"limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Still i keep getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## TL/DR:

remove mingw32 from path, push clang64\bin and usr\bin to the top of the path

Mine looks like this:

[image]

---

## Long answer:

The settings in c_cpp_properties are essentially only relevant for intellisense.

The configuration in tasks.json is responsible for compiling, and this configuration looks quite good to me.

My assumption is that the problem arises right at the beginning, namely with the path variable.

I also had massive problems with the MSYS2 compilers for a while, which I could not explain.

Note that when searching for anything to be found in the path, the first location found by searching from front to back is used.

Problems I see in this path are mainly :
Before the clang-path there is e.g. the path to Git. Also git provides a bash with numerous tools that are redundant with the msys2 bashes.

Mingw64 is still in the path. Many binaries are redundant there as well.
The clang path is far behind, a whole series of tools used in compiling could be found in completely different directories and used first.